# Passing terraform variable values from .tfvars file in the project folders to the module

Tags: variables, module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The following is my folder structure of my terraform project for AWS:

```
c:\terraform
   ├─modules
   │   └─ec2-fullstacks
   │       ├─main.tf
   │       └─variables.tf
   └─qa
       └─testappapi
           ├─testappapi_backend.tfvars
           ├─main.tf
           └─terraform.tfvars
```

**Under Module:**

The contents of `c:\terraform\modules\ec2-fullstacks\main.tf`:

```tf
provider "aws" {
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt = true
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "ami" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["${var.ec2_ami_name}*"]
  }
}

output "ami_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_ami.ami.id}"
}
```

The `c:\terraform\modules\ec2-fullstacks\variables.tf` contents:

```tf
variable "ec2_ami_name"  {}
variable "aws_account_name" {}
variable "aws_region" {}
```

**Under Project (testappapi):**

The contents of `C:\terraform\qa\testappapi\main.tf`:

```tf
provider "aws" {
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt = true
  }
}

module "testappapiqa" {
  source = "C:/terraform/modules/ec2-fullstacks"
}
```

The contents of `C:\terraform\qa\testappapi\terraform.tfvars`:

```tf
aws_account_name = "QA"
aws_region = "us-east-1"
ec2_ami_name = "WinAMI-2016-01-IIS"
```

The contents of `C:\terraform\qa\testappapi\testappapi_backend.tfvars`:

```tf
profile = "qa"
region = "us-east-1"
bucket = "tfstate-123456789012"
key = "qa/testappapi.tfstate"
dynamodb_table = "tfstate"
```

Here is what happens when I try to initialize:

```
C:\terraform\qa\testappapi>terraform get
- module.testappapi
  Getting source "C:/terraform/modules/ec2-fullstacks"

C:\terraform\qa\testappapi>terraform init -backend-config=testappapi_backend.tfvars
Initializing modules...
- module.testappapi

Initializing the backend...
Error: module "testappapi": missing required argument "ec2_ami_name"
Error: module "testappapi": missing required argument "aws_account_name"
Error: module "testappapi": missing required argument "aws_region"

C:\terraform\qa\testappapi>
```

I was expecting that the `source` in `main.tf` under project folder (`testappapi`) would get the values from the `terraform.tfvars` file under the same project folder, but it is not.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have created a module in `c:\terraform\modules\ec2-fullstacks\main.tf` with following mandatory variables

```
variable "ec2_ami_name"  {}
variable "aws_account_name" {}
variable "aws_region" {}
```

So while referring this module terraform expects you to pass these mandatory params as well. You can use it like this in `C:\terraform\qa\testappapi\main.tf`

```
module "testappapiqa" {
  source = "C:/terraform/modules/ec2-fullstacks"
  ec2_ami_name = "${var.ec2_ami_name}"
  aws_account_name = "${var.aws_account_name}"
  aws_region = "${var.aws_region}"
}
```

Now the main file is referring `ec2_ami_name, aws_account_name, aws_region` variables, which are not defined in `testappapi` folder. So you can define these variables in `C:\terraform\qa\testappapi\variables.tf`

```
variable "ec2_ami_name"  {}
variable "aws_account_name" {}
variable "aws_region" {}
```

Now this should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, this much I know. When I copy the variables.tf file from the module folder to the project folder and calling all data using "${var.<varaible_name>}", I won't consider this as full reusable of terraform codes.